# Como pausar bulce por "n" cantidad de segundos en js

Tags: nodejs, bucles, axios, async-await

A partir de un array ejecuto un **forEach** que por cada elemento hace una peticion a una API, para actualizar mi propia BD, el problema es que mientras mas elementos tenga el array mas peticiones tiene que hacer, y esto genera errores **429** por parte de la api, por esta razon **busco de cierta manera pausar el bucle por "n" cantidad de segundos**

```
arrayBD.map(async (e) => {
     try {

             const res = await axios.get("http://...") 
             //despues de recorrer cierta cantidad de elementos solo responde los 429
             //Justo aqui quisiera hacer la pausa para detener el bucle

     } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Error al datos ${err}`);
     }
});
```

Comment: Es extraño hacer tantas llamadas a una api, en general estas ofrecen la posibilidad de devolver un registro específico o listados, quizás deberías resolver eso, si es una api ya creada ver en la documentación si se pueden traer listados que cubran tus necesidades, si es una api que estás desarrollando podrías agregar un endpoint que te devuelva el listado que necesitas.. No es una buena idea realizar tantas llamadas a una API. La otra opción que podrías manejar es algun tipo de cache..

Comment: @LuisS.Romero es una api externa y esta me ofrece datos diarios, que los guardo en mi cache (redis); el fragmento de codigo que muestro pertenece a una funcion que actualiza mi cache a la medianoche a partir de los datos que quiero que actualice **arrayBD**

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar algo así, hice un ejemplo con la api de StarWars y con un array de IDs.

```
const charactersId = [1, 2, 3];

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function getCharacter() {
  for (const character of charactersId) {
    axios
      .get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${character}`)
      .then(await delay(5000))
      .then((character) => console.log(character.data));
  }
}


getCharacter();
```

---

En lugar del console.log haces lo que desees con la respuesta de la api, la cual hace una llamada cada tantos milisegundos como especifiques en el parámetro al llamar a delay().